# Spring Security is necessary for Stormpath?

Tags: spring-security, stormpath

Do I have to have Spring Security implemented in my Spring MVC web application to run Stormpath authentication?

**Background info:**

I want to create a web application for my friend's restaurant where people could go online and order food. There is no credit card charging in the webapp. Web application will just tell them the price and customers will have to pay at the counter.

Any input is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to use Spring Security if you do not want to. Stormpath provides it as an additional optional integration. You can see different [examples in their Github repo](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java/tree/master/examples). The ones that do not contain "spring-security" in their names do not have it (except for `spring-boot-default` which contains it as well). You can get extensive documentation in https://docs.stormpath.com/java